# Checkboxes that check another box

Tags: function, checkbox, parent-child, parent

I am working with a webpage that is full of checkboxes, I want to check 1 (let's call that parent) checkbox that has a function to check multiple other checkboxes (let's call those child). This until now has succeeded with this piece of jquery code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#1').on('change',function(){
     $('#5,#456,#910,#1077,#982,#759,#1234,#392,#289,#956').prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));
  });
    $('.child').on('change',function(){
     $('#parent').prop('checked',$('.child:checked').length ? true: false);
  });

});
```

The only thing is; I want to give functions to the "child" checkboxes and to let them work when the "parent" checkbox is checked, but the functions don't seem to work when the child checkbox is checked by the parent checkbox. Only when you manually check the childbox with your cursor.

I hope my question was clear. I normally don't post on here

:)

Comment: Please define what you mean by "but the functions don't seem to work when the child checkbox is checked by the parent checkbox". What do you expect to happen when the parent checkbox is checked? It seems you are trying to force an event chain, and it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like `$.trigger('click')` to check the box and trigger the click event with jQuery.

Try this:

```
$('#1').on('change',function(){
  $('#5,#456,#910,#1077,#982,#759,#1234,#392,#289,#956').trigger('click');
});
```

Here is a Stack Snippet to make it more clear:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#parent').click(function(){
     $('#1, #2, #3').trigger('click');
    });
    $('#1, #2, #3').click(function(){
      console.log(this.id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

parent: <input type="checkbox" id="parent" />

<br />

<input type="checkbox" id="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" />
```